# Columnar cipher transposition buffer in c

Tags: c, encryption

Good evening all, I'm trying to figure out how to build a buffer for a columnar cipher after reading the file in, I can't quite figure out how to implement the transposition to a columnar

```
int transpose_buffer(char *out, char *in, unsigned int dim) {
unsigned int transpositionmatrix[dim][dim]; //transposition matrix reads in values to the dim dim matrix
    int i, j;
        for(i=0; i<dim; i++){
                for(j=0,i<dim;j++;){
                    scanf(*in, &transpositionmatrix[dim][dim]);
                }
        }
```

is anyone aware of how to shift rows to columns and columns to rows after i've read in this file?

thank you!

Comment: Aside: Is that your real code? The `scanf` is clearly either not real code or will result in undefined behaviour. The first arg needs to be a `char *` whereas you give it a `char`. The second arg is a pointer past the end of the buffer and should instead be `transpositionmatrix[i][j]`.

Comment: To transpose a matrix just create a new array and copy to index `[i][j]` from the original array's index `[j][i]` in a loop.